# Usage of BEGIN/END and GO in a SQL query when altering a primary key in a record

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having a weird syntax error when trying to update the primary key of a record in my DB. Is the use of `BEGIN/END` and `GO` incorrect here?

```sql
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM dbo.Settings 
               WHERE Descr = 'GL for Credit Memo' AND SettingID = 198)
BEGIN
SET IDENTITY_INSERT Settings ON
GO

    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Settings]
                ([SettingID],
                [Created],
                [Descr],
                [Category],
                [OrderNo],
                [DataType],
                [InActive],
                [IsRequired])
            VALUES
                (198,
                GETDATE(),
                'GL for Credit Memo',
                'Accounting',
                7,
                4,
                NULL,
                1)

DELETE FROM [dbo].[Settings] WHERE descr = 'GL for Credit Memo' AND SettingID = 200

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Settings] off
GO
END
```

In the example above I want to insert a new record with a specific primary key (SettingID) and remove the existing one.

Comment: I ended up moving the `SET IDENTITY_INSERT` lines outside of the `BEGIN/END` blocks and that seems to have fixed the error, but would love a second opinion.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The above code is product specific.)

Comment: I'm using MSSQL @jarlh

Comment: `GO` isn't a standard SQL keyword, it's a batch separator that's specific to certain clients like SQL Server Management Studio and `sqlcmd`. You can't have `GO` appearing in the middle of `BEGIN`...`END` blocks, either.

Comment: Just remove the `GO` lines. They aren't needed here anyway